# EF Code First One-to-One AND One-to-Many mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-model-builder

I have the following model and I am trying to construct a one-to-one and also one-to-many relationships from the same parent and child entities. The one-to-many relationship works with my current mappings but I am struggling with adding the new one-to-one relationship (for CoverPicture property). Here are the relevant model and EF mapping codes:

Category.cs:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Guid? CoverPictureId { get; set; }
public virtual Picture CoverPicture { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
```

Picture.cs:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string FileName { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Relevant Category `EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>` mappings (incorrect):

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.CoverPicture)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CoverPictureId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Relevant Picture `EntityTypeConfiguration<Picture>` mappings (correct):

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Category)
    .WithMany(t => t.Pictures)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.CategoryId);
```

When I try to add a migration for the new `CoverPicture` property, EF tries to add a `CoverPictureId` column to the `Category` table (which is what I want) but also `CoverPictureId` to the `Picture` table (which is not what I want; `Picture` already has a key defined and mapped).

Here is the `Up()` migration code scaffolded by EF:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Category", "CoverPictureId", c => c.Guid());
AddColumn("dbo.Picture", "CoverPictureId", c => c.Int());
CreateIndex("dbo.Picture", "CoverPictureId");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Picture", "CoverPictureId", "dbo.Category", "Id");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of EF you are using, but newer versions won't allow you to do the type of mapping you're trying to do, you'll receive the following error:

> The navigation property 'Pictures' declared on type 'YourProject.Category' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.

So why is that? Let's look at your mappings, and what you're telling Entity Framework in plain English:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Category)  //A Picture must have 1 Category
.WithMany(t => t.Pictures)         //A Category can have many Pictures


this.HasOptional(t => t.CoverPicture) //A Category may or may not have 1 Picture
.WithRequired()                       //A Picture must have 1 Category
```

Compare that with octavioccl's answer:

```
this.HasOptional(p => p.CoverPicture) //A Category may or may not have 1 Picture 
.WithMany()                           //A Picture can have many Categories
```

The change from WithRequired to WithMany is swapping where the Foreign Key is being placed. Now you have the mapping that you're looking for... kind of:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Categories",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(),
            CoverPicture_Id = c.Guid(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Pictures", t => t.CoverPicture_Id)
    .Index(t => t.CoverPicture_Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Pictures",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            FileName = c.String(),
            Category_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.Category_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.Category_Id);
```

But let's stop and think about that for a second. Not only have you basically defined 1 to many relationships in both directions (not to be confused with many to many) but you've also broken the integrity of your model. Now you can assign a `Picture` as a `Category`'s `CoverPicture` even if that `Picture` doesn't belong to that `Category`. That's not what you want, and eventually it's going to cause you a headache. Instead of explicitly defining a `CoverPicture` property on `Category`, how about this?

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    public SetCoverPicture(Picture picture)
    {
        if(!Pictures.Contains(picture))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Picture is not in this Category");
        }
        var currentCoverPicture = Pictures.FirstOrDefault(p=p.IsCoverPicture == true);
        if(currentCoverPictur e!= null)
        {
            currentCoverPicture.IsCoverPicture = false;
        }
        picture.IsCoverPicture = true;
    }

}

public class Picture
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoverPicture { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

This enforces your invariants (business rules) that state that...

1. a `CoverPicture` for a `Category` must belong to that `Category`
   (enforced by the database) and
2. there can be only 1 `CoverPicture`
   for a `Category` (enforced in code)

You could do something similar with the code provided by octavioccl, but the code provided here results in a cleaner and more understandable physical data model.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue try to map that relationship as I show below:

```
this.HasOptional(p => p.CoverPicture)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.CoverPictureId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In one-to-one relation one end must be **principal** and second end must be **dependent**. When you are configuring this kind of relationship, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key. With your configuration, the principal is `Category` and the dependend is `Picture`. That's way FK `CoverPictureId` is `int` instead `Guid`, because this is really the `Category` PK as your migration code has interpreted.